# How to get url, that app try to reach?

Tags: android

I would like to know, how to get url, that app try to reach?

For example if "Angry Bird" try to reach www.ab.com/update.txt i would like to know about this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you try out this: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=725692
It's a packet sniffer for android that dumps the traces to a pcap file on your sdcard. This pcap file can be read with Wireshark.
For the app, you will need to root your device.